# How to pass objects between functions in PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have to functions.  In the first, I create a reference to a SharePoint list.  I would like to pass the list to a second function.  In the second functions list of parameters, I declare it as `String`

This doesn't work.  How do I declare the parameter as being a list?

```
function GetList()
{
    param(
    [string] $listID,
    [string] $listName
    )
    Write-Host "Provided ListName: " $listName -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host "The list id is: " $listID -ForegroundColor Red

    $list = Get-PnPList -Identity $listName

     CreateView -list $list

}

function CreateView() 
{
    param(
    [string] $list
    )

    Add-PnpView -Title "Test View" -List $list -Fields "Title"
    Write-Host "Creating New View"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official documentation below:

[Get-PnPList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/Get-PnPList)

> 1. Returns a List Object
> 2. And outputs **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List**

So instead of using it as a string try using its return type you get.

You can also get the type returned from `Get-PnPList`, using:

```
$list.GetType().FullName
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks.  Makes perfect sense!